# Allow apigee togo console from only one IP

Tags: api, apigee

I have designed a Apigee TO-GO console I want it to be accessed only from my server is it possible. I gone through Apigee control policy but unable to understand how to achieve that. Here is link of Apigee access control policy.

http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/reference/access-control-policy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to make To-Go Console's URL private. Also it cannot be accessed by everyone unless you share the actual URL. The policy you are looking at refers to the APIs configured in the 'API Management' and has nothing to do with the To-Go Console.